# Aligning an html form so all labels link up

Tags: php, html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align my form up so that all labels start at the same and then also the textboxes start at the same spot. When using float:left all the labels are starting at the same point but the textboxes just follow on so textboxes are all messed up. Is there a way I can set so that all textboxes so start at a specific point on the page. I am using CSS but not to sure which attributes I need to be using. The form I've got is;

```
<form method="POST" action="editloaninfo.php">

<div id="editp"Username:
<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" size="18" value="<?php  echo $username; ?>"></div>

<br>

<div id="editp"Product:
<select name="product" style="width: 150px">
    <option value="<?php echo $product;?>">
    <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option value="Keyboard">Keyboard</option>
</select></div>
```

The div for edit is;

```
#editp {

font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 80%;
margin-right: 100px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: It will be very helpful if you create a fiddle

Comment: @SohaibMohammed never created a fiddle nor am i sure what it even is?

Comment: You don't seem to be closing your initial div, also this is JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/. Cut the relevant code out and replicate the issue there so that we can see it. Also you could just set a width on your labels to the length of the longest one, so all of the options next to them align.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just need to set a width on the label, to that of the longest label so that elements next to them align with each other.

See this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/yya26ark/

HTML:

```
<label>Example Label:</label><input type="text">
<label>Example:</label><input type="text">
<label>Label Ex:</label><input type="text">
<label>Something Else Here:</label><input type="text">
```

CSS:

```
label { display:inline-block; width:200px; }
input { width:120px; }
```

Comment: How would I put the css for the label & input in a sort of class so that it doesn't affect the input etc on other pages.

Comment: You can add a class to an element like this - <label class="labelWidth"> - and then in your CSS you would link styles to it using - .labelWidth { STYLES HERE }. Alternatively you could assign a class to the table and then target the elements inside it like so - .tableClass label -.

Comment: cheers, that sorted it - I was trying to put them in a div which is where I was going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Close your opening div tags. You're missing a `>`.

Don't use inline styles

Use form labels!

Then just use inline block and widths to control positioning of labels to inputs:

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  }
label {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  }
input,
select {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="editloaninfo.php">

<div id="editp">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" value="<?php  echo $username; ?>">
</div>

<br>

<div id="editp">
  <label for="product">Product:</label>
  <select name="product">
    <option value="<?php echo $product;?>">
    <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option value="Keyboard">Keyboard</option>
  </select>
</div>

</form>
```